# Create a batch file to copy and rename file

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I need to write a batch file that copies a file to a new folder and renames it.

At the moment, my batch file consists of only this command:

```
COPY ABC.PDF \\Documents
```

As you can see, it only copies the file `ABC.pdf` to the network folder `Documents`.

However I need to change this so it renames the file `ABCxxx.pdf`, where `xxx` is a text variable that I would like to set somewhere in the batch file.

For example, if `xxx` = `_Draft`, then file would be renamed `ABC_Draft.pdf` after it is copied.

Comment: Could `copy ABC_*.PDF \\Documents` do the trick?

Answer (score 43):

Make a bat file with the following in it:

```
copy /y C:\temp\log1k.txt C:\temp\log1k_copied.txt
```

However, I think there are issues if there are spaces in your directory names.  Notice this was copied to the same directory, but that doesn't matter.  If you want to see how it runs, make another bat file that calls the first and outputs to a log:

```
C:\temp\test.bat > C:\temp\test.log
```

(assuming the first bat file was called test.bat and was located in that directory)

Comment: Thanks

If i wanted to copy and rename all PDFs in that folder with the same text suffix, how would i do that?

For example, if i have 2 pdfs ABC.PDF and ZYZ.pdf and i want to copy and rename them both to my 'Documents' folder' as ABCxxx.PDF and ZYZxxx.pdf, where "xxx" is the same text variable, how woudl i do that?

Comment: If you use copy /y C:\temp\*.PDF C:\tempcopy\*Copied.PDF, you won't quite get what you want, although it's in the right direction.  Starting with files like ABC.PDF and DRE.PDF, I ended up with copies in that folder called ABCopied.PDF and DRE.PDFCopied.PDF.  I'm not good with regular expressions, but I think something like that is what you need.

Comment: @Konstantin - but it won't ever be accepted as an answer, because the person asking the question hasn't been back for the last 5+ years.

Comment: I can confirm this works with quotes around the directory names that contain spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply overwrite the file with `type`. (It works best with text files.)

```
type C:\temp\test.txt > C:\temp\test_copy.txt
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer and add a short explanation of what it does and how it works? Thank you!