# Switch between two files using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a scenario where I have a file called `file.ini` in my C:\Windows\ folder.

But I want to create a batch file that will keep this file to `file_mr.ini` but then also rename it to file.ini.

So it would look like this, basically a switch:

```
C:\Windows\
- file.ini

C:\Windows\
- file_mr.ini -> file.ini
(keeping the file_mr.ini and not removing it)

C:\Windows\
- file_original.ini -> file.ini
(keeping the file_original.ini and not removing it)
```

This is what I have tried:

File created: `Enable mr.cmd` > edited:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET old=file_mr
SET new=file
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('C:\Windows\ /b *.ini') do (
  SET newname=%%f
  SET newname=!newname:%old%=%new%!
  move "%%f" "!newname!"
)
```

File created: `Disable mr.cmd` > edited:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET old=file_original
SET new=file
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('C:\Windows\ /b *.ini') do (
  SET newname=%%f
  SET newname=!newname:%old%=%new%!
  move "%%f" "!newname!"
)
```

But this is good (not tested yet) to rename the file and remove the original file) - which is not what I want.

Just the same as you can do it manually, by copying the file and renaming the copied file.

Comment: This may be the answer I am looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058054/create-a-batch-file-to-copy-and-rename-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a look at the linked question, and am using this answer:

`Enable mr.cmd`:

```
copy /y C:\windows\file.ini C:\windows\file_original.ini
copy /y C:\windows\file_mr.ini C:\windows\file.ini
```

And

`Disable mr.cmd`:

```
copy /y C:\windows\file.ini C:\windows\file_mr.ini
copy /y C:\windows\file_original.ini C:\windows\file.ini
```

UPDATE:

After more investigation, this is now working as expected:

`MR Enable.bat`:

```
find "C:\mr_folder\" C:\Windows\file.ini >nul && call
copy /y C:\Windows\file.ini C:\Windows\file_original.ini
copy /y C:\Windows\file_mr.ini C:\Windows\file.ini
```

`MR Disable.bat`:

```
find "C:\mr_folder\" C:\Windows\file.ini >nul && call
copy /y C:\windows\file.ini C:\windows\file_mr.ini
copy /y C:\windows\file_original.ini C:\windows\file.ini
```

Comment: On Linux, you would do this sort of thing with symbolic links, you would have your two different files and then just create a link from `file.ini` to whichever one you wanted to use. I believe there is a `mklink` on Windows now... https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell, but I am glad I don't have to do this (yet) on Linux :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this to automatically detect whether the current file `file.ini` is a copy of `file_mr.ini` or `file_original.ini` and toggle, so you do not need two batch files:

```cmd
rem // Change to working directory:
pushd "C:\Windows"
rem // Compare current `file.ini` file with `file_original.ini`:
fc "file.ini" "file_original.ini" > nul 2>&1 && (
    rem // Files match, so exchange `file.ini` with copy of `file_mr.ini`:
    copy /Y "file_mr.ini" "file.ini" > nul
    echo Copied file `file_mr.ini`.
) || (
    rem // Files did not match or `file.ini` not found:
    copy /Y "file_original.ini" "file.ini" > nul
    echo Copied file `file_original.ini`.
)
popd
```

Note that you need write privileges to the file `C:\Windows\file.ini`.

Comment: Ah, that would make life easier haha